# My SD card is missing 2 GB of space

Tags: external-sd, storage, partitions, ext4

i have a 16 GB samsung SD card (~14.8 GB of usable space). As i have a rooted phone, i tried to partition my SD card into a 2GB ext4 and rest as the FAT16 partition, using MiniTool Partition wizard.

After i applied the changes, the minitool partition wizard has been showing me only 1 partition of the sd card disk with only 12.8 GB of usable space (FAT16) (the ext4 partition is missing). Even my android can't find the ext4 partition on the SD card. I have been googling for hours, still can't find a solution. 
Supposedly, it should show me approx 2 GB of unallocated space, but it is not.

Basically, 2 GB of space just vanished from my card. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to format the card in a device other than a computer or Android device. As example a camera that supports the card. This must solve partition / space allocation problems.